# Is ALS deterministic?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, recommendation-engine

I have a question about ALS used for recommendation engines? Is ALS deterministic? As in, if you put in the same data and the same parameters, should you always get the same output (or a very similar outcome)?

Comment: If you want to read about recommender systems, I think you can read this [Recommender Systems](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/mmds/ch9.pdf)

Comment: You can learn more about ALS by reading [this paper](http://www.grappa.univ-lille3.fr/~mary/cours/stats/centrale/reco/paper/MatrixFactorizationALS.pdf)

Answer (score 4):

The short response should be: NO. The great part of Matrix Factorization algos start with random initialization of the feature matrix. So the issue is that you could find several "local" minimum's during several run of the optimization process.

Comment: Why is that a "great" part?

Comment: Some implementations use a static initialization of the starting matrix. But in any case they use some randomness to avoid find always local minimum

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the seed used by the random number generator, in which case the results are completely deterministic.